# Combine values of two rows to one

Tags: mysql, sql

```
    I have data like 
    user Id         colA        colB
    12              abc         NULL
    13              123         NULL
    13              NULL        567

    I want output like

    user Id         colA        colB
    12              abc         NULL
    13              123         567
```

Comment: If user ID is the same for multiple rows will there be only one non-NULL value for each column? If not then you need to decide what to do with the values, e.g. find the max, min, sum, ...

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT
user_Id, MAX(colA) colA, MAX(colB) colB
FROM tbl
GROUP BY user_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select user_id , 
if (colA = NULL , 0 , max(colA)) colA ,
if (colB = NULL, 0 , max(colB)) colB
from a
group by user_id
```

output will be:

```
 USER_ID    COLA    COLB
   12       abc     (null)
   13       123     567
```

[**DEMO SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f0f6/9)