# Get Identity after selecting from distinct result

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have 2 tables ( Model_Table , Items_Table)

```
Model_Tabl ( ID, ModelName, ModelQuantity)
Items_Tabl ( I_Code, IName, ID)
```

after inserting new row into (Model_Table) - Triggers insert multi row into (Items_Table) Depend on ModelQuantity from (Model_Table) , and until now its work fine

I Created

```
"select distinct ModelName , Sum(ModelQuantity) group by ModelName"
```

and i got result fine

My question is :

When i select model name from (DISTINCT) query i want to know which (ID) I selected from (Model_Table)

(Model_ID) to (ModelName) = 1 to many

ty

Comment: i guess you want know which id from `Items_Tabl` ??

Comment: i dont really understand this `(Model_ID) to (ModelName) = 1 to many`

Comment: where is this `Model_ID` ?

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Models](
 [ModelId] [bigint] IDENTITY ,
 [ModelName] [nchar](20) ,
 [ModelQ] [int] ,
 [ModelPrice] [money] ,
)

Comment: i really need help plz dont feel board from me :)

Comment: just explain what you want

Comment: can we talk on yahoo so i can send db to you and you can tell me whata right to do ? if not just say no and i will try to explain again

Comment: i guess you want know which id from Items_Tabl ??   yes this right but after i select model name from distinct query cuz i dont want to douplecate model_name as it model_name can hold same name but not same id

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941934/combine-values-of-two-rows-to-one  , can u give some data from your tables and how you want the result as in this question link ?

Comment: ty all for help i think i gave heahach :)

Comment: you welcome to post your problem i will be pleased to help you Karem

Comment: thx alot mr.echo_me you a good person and sory for late with answer i was outside with my (Note) to add edieas :)

Comment: and i got the idea and wrote alot of example will see now :S what i can do in SQL

Comment: i fix it :) and now iam able to update 3 tables when i add purchase order for my shop ty for help
i creat another table to colect same name and update quantity so i dont need to distinct columns just i add in in operations and update in stor if exist and if not add new record to store ( thx mr.echo)

Answer (score 0):

just select also the id ,try this

```
 select id, ModelName , Sum(ModelQuantity) 
 from Model_Tabl group by ModelName
```

you dont need `DISTINCT` because you already making group by and they do same work

Comment: @jcho360 what where ? i dont understand what he mean by `(Model_ID) to (ModelName) = 1 to many` is this the where ?

Comment: its my fault sorry but this first time i ask a question on internet most time iam only thinking

Comment: Don't forget that you also need to group by the `id` column when you add it to the select list.